# Queue In a C# Ilist

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list with 5 elements...What I want to move foward all elements, removing the last one and add a new value to the first one. Is there any pre-made list methods that do that or help me so?
Like a Queue

Comment: Is it important that you add to the front and remove from the back of the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

Edit: Your wording can be interpreted a couple different ways but if you want a first in first out behavior then use a `Queue<T>`.  If you want a first in last out behavior then use a `Stack<T>`.

Comment: Be aware that the Queue<T> class does this, but in reverse of the OP's specified order.  This is only a partially true answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about [Queue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), as suggested numerous times.  Be aware, however, that Queue will add items to the end, and remove from the front, which is the opposite behavior that you specified.  If you're using this collection as an `IEnumerable<T>` and enumerating it, the `Queue<T>` will be backwards from your specifications.

There are two ways to work around this easily.  You could iterate the queue in reverse if you treat this as an enumerable by using Enumerable.Reverse().

Alternatively, you could use a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx).  This allows you to insert and remove from both the beginning and the end of the collection.  This would let you preserve the ordering you specified.

If the order doesn't matter, and you just need a general purpose queue, then `Queue<T>` is definitely the best choice.

Comment: I think he was describing a queue just with a bit strange wording.

Comment: @Brian: Not sure.  He definitely specified adding at the front, and removing from the "back", which is the opposite of how Queue<T> is implemented.  It may or may not matter (I tried to clarify this in my answer), but if it does, Queue<T> will be wrong.

Comment: @Brian: I question it mainly because he did use the word queue, so I'm assuming the OP knows about queues. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) class.  It should provide all the methods you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.QUEUE%601%22);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true)

Comment: Heh:

answered 43 secs ago Brian R. Bondy

answered 16 secs ago spender

answered 4 secs ago luke

answered 0 secs ago Cory Charlton

Brian wins ;-)